# Can PHP pass a long string to an exec-ed process via STDIN or commandline argument?

Tags: php

I want PHP to send a 10000-character JSON array to a Java program and get a JSON array in return.

There is the exec() method for calling subprocesses, but I dont know how to reliably pass a long string. I see two methods:

**Method 1:** Pass the entire string in the commandline. I am worried how to escape a JSON string for the commandline and if it is too much for a Linux commandline to handle. ROFLMAO anyone?

**Method 2:** Make the java program wait for a `\n`-terminated string from STDIN. PHP can send the string to the STDIN of that Java program.

What is a good method to pass a long string to a Java subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm wouldn't a temporary file as input be the cleanest solution here? Sorry if this won't suit but it probably would make life easier for debugging too

Comment: Wish I could give you an extra upvote. Other methods (even shared database) will be a total PITA.